# Missing artifact leadtools:ocr:jar:1.0

Tags: java, leadtools-sdk

I have added the jars of leadTools in my maven project and have stored those jars locally in my `.m2` folder. But in `pom.xml`, I am getting the following error -

Missing artifact leadtools:ocr:jar:1.0

Here's my customised dependency -

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>leadtools</groupId>
        <artifactId>ocr</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

path where I have stored the jar - 
    `/home/admin13/.m2/repository/leadtools/ocr/1.0/ocr-1.0.jar`

Comment: Instead of copying the JAR file to your local Maven repository manually, try installing it using `mvn install`. For detailed instructions, see: [Guide to installing 3rd party JARs](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html)

Comment: I have already tried it, it's successful from command line. But still maven can't find dependency when I build my project on eclipse.

Comment: Did you install it using the correct groupId, artifactId and version (the exact same as you use in your `pom.xml`)?

Comment: Yes Jesper, I did same.

Answer (score 0):

You need to match up the GroupID and the ArtifactID with the actuall LEADTOOLS namespace names: i.e. leadtools.forms.ocr

Also, you will need to add a system path (relative or absolute) to the dependency

Here is an example:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>leadtools.forms.ocr</groupId>
   <artifactId>leadtools.forms.ocr</artifactId>
   <version>1.0</version>
   <scope>system</scope>
  <systemPath>C:\Public\workspace\leadtools\leadtools.form.ocr.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I added  <dependency>
   <groupId>leadtools.forms.ocr</groupId>
   <artifactId>leadtools.forms.ocr</artifactId>
   <version>1.0</version>                                                                                     
   <scope>system</scope>
  <systemPath>/home/admin13/Downloads/LEADTOOLS19/Bin/Java/leadtools.form.ocr.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>                                                                                                    but this is not working, it's giving same error.

Comment: I just made a new Maven project in Eclipse and tested the exact code I sent you above and it added the dependency without error. I do not know what you are doing wrong